# Selecting and resizing a table using xlwing

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I want to know how one can select an existing table in an excel file using xlwings and resize it to a new value. I only see how to create a new one, but not how to select and manipulate an existing one. If it is not possible, could it be done with openpyxl or other python library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried using the `resize` method (https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/xlwings/v0.6.4/xlwings.pdf), but it doesn't seem to work...